# Find intersection between two arrays of objects of different length

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays of objects that share a property with the same name (`userId`), but have different lengths. Here is a simple example:

```js
const arr1= [
    {
        userId: "1", 
        name:"Tommy", 
        hobbies:"fighting"
    }, 
    {
       userId: "16", 
       name:"Kino", 
       hobbies:"skating"
    }
];

const arr2= [
    {
        userId: "1", 
        story:"Big fight"
    }, 
    {
        userId:"16",
        story:"big momentum"
    }
];
```

My ideal outcome would be to have one array which combines both objects that match in property with `userId` (and all objects that match in property) and keeps all of the properties of both.

I´ve tried using `concat` and then filtering, but to no avail. Any clues or suggestion on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: Not really. They are array of objects, not individual objects.

Comment: What do you want as the output of `story` property if an user exist in `arr1` but not `arr2`? undefined?

Answer (score 1):

This can be a possible solution:

```js
const arr1 = [{userId: "1", name:"Tommy", hobbies:"fighting"}, {userId: "16", name:"Kino", hobbies:"skating"}];
const arr2 = [{userId: "1", story:"Big fight"}, {userId:"16", story:"big momentum"}];

const obj = [...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((acc, el) => {
  acc[el.userId] = {...acc[el.userId], ...el};
  
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = Object.values(obj);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You can simplify this by using `const result = Object.values(obj);`

Comment: @Titus Wow thanks a lot. I didn't know that API. I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like:

```js
function combByPropVal(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), prop = a.shift(), val = a.shift(), o = {};
  a[0].forEach(obj=>{
    if(prop in obj && obj[prop] === val){
      o[prop] = val;
      for(let i in obj){
        if(i !== prop)o[i] = obj[i];
      }
    }
  });
  return o;
}
const arr1 = [{userId: "1", name:"Tommy", hobbies:"fighting"}, {userId: "16", name:"Kino", hobbies:"skating"}];
const arr2 = [{userId: "1", story:"Big fight"}, {userId:"16", story:"big momentum"}];
console.log(combByPropVal('userId', '1', arr1.concat(arr2)));
```

`combByPropVal` takes three arguments `property`, `value`, and an `Array of Objects`. I used `.concat` to create a new Array before passing it in.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have two arrays, `arr1` and `arr2`. Length of `arr1` might be longer or equals to `arr2`. Difference between an object in `arr2` and `arr1` is the `story` property.

```
const arr1 = [
  { userId: "1", name: "Tommy", hobbies: "fighting" }, 
  { userId: "16", name: "Kino", hobbies: "skating" }, 
  { userId: "17", name: "Tom", hobbies: "Tennis" }
];
const arr2 = [
  { userId: "1", story: "Big fight" }, 
  { userId: "16", story: "big momentum" }
];
```

```
const result = arr1.map(obj1 => {
  const obj2IfExist = arr2.find(obj2 => obj2.userId === obj1.userId);
  obj1['story'] = obj2IfExist? obj2IfExist['story'] : null;
  return obj1
})

console.log(result)
```

That's what you got:

```
[
  { userId: "1", name: "Tommy", hobbies: "fighting", story: "Big fight" },
  { userId: "16", name: "Kino", hobbies: "skating", story: "big momentum" },
  { userId: "17", name: "Tom", hobbies: "Tennis", story: null }
]
```